# How to allocate memory on these two functions

Tags: c

```
char* bit_encrypt(const unsigned char* text) 

unsigned char* bit_decrypt(const char* text)
```

Hello how do I allocate memory and return value on those 2 types of function with unsigned? 
I got this error when I was trying to do allocation in the first function

```
error: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]

unsigned char* binary = (unsigned char*)malloc((strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem at my end. Can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @cse I don't think it's important to reproduce problem. Basic C knowledge can solve it.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk May be you are right. But, I can't suggest any solution because I can't reproduce it. May be problem be in other part of code. __You are free to predict(based on error log). But I'm not that smart ;)__

Comment: Well, OP shows us error log and line where thing happens, and we know that text is unsigned char* from definition above, so at least I think that we are able to solve it without full source code. He is just missing cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have simply, to cast unsigned char* to char*. Like so:

```
unsigned char* binary = (unsigned char*)malloc(strlen((char*)text) + 1);
```

You don't have to cast malloc result like you did. It is unnecessary, as `void *` is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type in this case. And it adds clutter to the code, casts are not very easy to read (especially if the pointer type is long, like unsigned char).

As suggested by Basile Starynkevitch, you don't have to multiply by `sizeof(char)`. Finally, code will look like this:

```
unsigned char* binary = malloc(strlen((char*)text) + 1);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 *by definition* (on all platforms)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well, going to get rid of it, thanks!

Comment: **error: pointer targets in return differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]
 return binary;**
... And how do I return this value? :)

Comment: Cast this one too.

Comment: I can't see your code dude, just try solving it on your own or show us code.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar In C you get an implicit conversion from void* to any other (data) pointer. Edit: After you corrected your comment, It's right, but we already do not cast malloc result.

Comment: Also, dear @M3LeeOP, did you include `<stdlib.h>`? If not, do this.